# django ModelForm save() method issue

Tags: python, django, save, modelform

I have a model form:

```
class SnippetForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        exclude = ['author', 'slug']
```

and I want to be able to edit a particular instance by using this:

```
def edit_snippet(request, snippet_id):
    #look up for that snippet
    snippet = get_object_or_404(Snippet, pk=snippet_id)
    if request.user.id != snippet.author.id:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SnippetForm(data=request.POST, instance=snippet)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(snippet.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        form = SnippetForm(instance=snippet)
    return render_to_response(SNIPPET_EDIT_TEMPLATE,
                              {'form':form, 'add':False, 'user':request.user}, 
                              RequestContext(request))
```

Notice that at the line

`form = SnippetForm(data=request.POST, instance=snippet)`

, I created a form that use the data supplied from the user, and bound it with the instance found using the primary key (received from the url). According to [django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method), when I call save() the existing instance should be updated with POSTED data. Instead, what I see is a new object is created and saved into the database. What went wrong? Thanks a lot.

[Edit] This is really embarrassed. The code indeed has nothing wrong with it. The only thing that messed up the whole thing was the action I put in the template (as I use a same template for add and edit a snippet)....Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate that.

Comment: Try to debug it, I think the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code as posted - it should update the existing instance.

Comment: Can you explain what was wrong with the action? I think I may be having the same problem, but I'm not sure how the action would affect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why it would happen. What version of django is it?

In any case, you can manually force update passing the corresponding argument.

```
form = SnippetForm(data=request.POST, instance=snippet, force_update=True)
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. I'm using django 1.2.4. Thanks anyway.