# Why I can't save the edit of a Django ModelForm blog?

Tags: django, python-3.x, modelform

I was doing the Python Crash Course Ex. 19-1: Blogs, and I'm now stuck at saving the edit of any blog. I tried plugging in the .errors code in the blog.html (for showing each blog) but it shows nothing, so I guess my templates has no field errors (?)

---

Here're some codes I believe crucial for solving the not-saving-the-edit problem. The new_blog function in views.py works fine so I'll skip it.

The edit_blog function in views.py:

```py
def edit_blog(request, blog_id):
    idk = BlogPost.objects.get(id = blog_id)
    if request.method != "POST":
        form = BlogForm(instance = idk)
    else:
        form = BlogForm(instance = idk, data = request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogs:blogs'))

    content = {"editing_blog": form, "psst": idk}
    return render(request, 'blogs/edit_blog.html', content)
```

new_blog.html:

```html
{% extends "blogs/all.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Write a new blog:</p>

    <form action="{% url 'blogs:new_blog' %}" method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table border="1">
            {{ new_blog }}
        </table>
        <p></p>
        <button name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

edit_blog.html:

```html
{% extends "blogs/all.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Edit the blog:</p>

    <form action="{% url 'blogs:blog' psst.id %}" method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table border="1">
            {{ editing_blog }}
        </table>
        <p></p>
        <button name="submit">Save changes</button>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Btw, the urlpattern is here:

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'blogs'

urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.homepage, name = 'homepage'),

    # Show all blogs.
    path('blogs/', views.blogs, name = 'blogs'),

    # Show the detail of a blog.
    path('blogs/<int:blog_id>', views.blog, name = 'blog'),

    # Page for adding a new blog.
    path('new_blog/', views.new_blog, name = 'new_blog'),

    # Page for editing a blog.
    path('edit_blog/<int:blog_id>', views.edit_blog, name = 'edit_blog'),
]
```

---

No matter how I change the title, or content, or both of the blog I don't see the changes saved. Is it:

A) My form action in edit_blog.html goes wrong, as [wakandan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743967/) mentioned?

B) I need to adjust something in edit_blog view function, like [Bibhas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739701/) said?

Many thanks. Also tell me if I need to add more codes for understanding.

Comment: Does your edit_blog function get called, write a print statement and see if the form submission really submits to edit_blog function.

Comment: The print statement on the shell, the views.py or template?

Comment: Could you please provide urlpattern which you use to match the path to `edit_blog` view?

Comment: Sure. See the code part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form action is currently set to `{% url 'blogs:blog' psst.id %}`, which means you're posting to your `views.blog` view, which is just a detail view. You need to change the action to `{% url 'blogs:edit_blog' psst.id %}` so that the form is posted to your edit view.

It's not clear from the code you have posted where the `editing_blog` context variable is coming from - you will need to make sure that this is an instance of the same form that your edit view is looking for, otherwise you'll run into other problems.

Finally also note that you are not currently handling the case where the form has errors - i.e., there is no `else` condition specified for `form.is_valid()`.

Comment: No worry on the ```editing_blog``` variable. If I change it to other names both in the ```edit_blog``` template and the ```content``` dict of ```edit_blog``` view function it works.